# В чем смысл полиморфизма?

Tags: полиморфизм

Для чего использовать полиморфизм, кроме как для красоты и удобства кода?

Comment: _кроме как для красоты и удобства кода?_ - на чём построено такое убеждение? Привидите пример.

Comment: @0xab на том, что не замечаю других улучшений в коде кроме этого, нигде не написано про какие то другие улучшения характеристик по типу оптимизации и т.п.

Comment: По сути, "вот это вот всё" сделано для красоты и удобства кода. Тру программисты пишут сразу в машинных кодах ;-)

Comment: А разве есть вещи важнее? Иногда даже быстродействием ради этого жертвуют.

Comment: Вы не привели примера, на чём строится ваше суждение. _нигде не написано_, а что написано? Дайте ссылку на источник.

Comment: А вообще, чтобы понять смысл полиморфизма, попробуйте на чистом C попрограммировать какую-нибудь игру или сложную программу. Все привыкли к ООП, а иногда мне самому бывает интересно вспомнить, как люди жили без него.

Comment: @Kromster машинные коды это было уже удобно =)

Comment: @0xdb почти везде где поднимается эта тема говорят так

Comment: @trollingchar разве красота важнее оптимизации ?

Comment: @NeulovimFox может показаться неожиданным, но часто это так. Если есть два способа решить задачу, и один из них очень красивый, а второй некрасивый, но на 5% быстрее, я предпочту первый. Красивый код проще читать и как следствие в нем меньше багов.

Comment: Красота и удобство кода порой перевешивают всё остальное и позволяют писать код в сотни раз короче. Посмотрите на WPF и попробуйте написать свою собственную панель размещения с логикой. Все компоненты имеют одинаковый код - Arrange, Measure и DesiredSize. Или возьмите [руководство от Майкрософт](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) и перепишите первый же код без полиморфизма. А потом представьте, что в каком-нибудь Unity тысячи разных объектов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Задам встречный вопрос, после описания некой ситуации.

Предположим, у Вас есть 3 машины, разных моделей, но использующие в качестве топлива один и тот же ресурс и имеющие одинаковый механизм пополнения топлива. Так же есть условная станция, которая поставляет Вам этот ресурс.

Опишем приведенный пример без использования полиморфизма:

```
class Car1
{
  string model_name;
  float f_volume;
}

class Car2
{
  string model_name;
  float f_volume;
}

class Car3
{
  string model_name;
  float f_volume;
}
```

Отлично, вот наш маленький автопарк :) Теперь пробуем описать станцию:

```
class Station
{
 float cost;

 public void fill_up_for_car1(Car1 car, int liters)
 {
   //awesome_code
 }
 public void fill_up_for_car2(Car2 car, int liters)
 {
   //awesome_code
 }
 public void fill_up_for_car3(Car3 car, int liters)
 {
   //awesome_code
 }
}
```

Довольно легко запутаться, не так ли? Конкретный метод "заправки" для конкретной машины, и не имей мы полиморфизма, представьте, сколько этих методов придется добавить владельцу станции, чтобы справиться с миллиардами автомобилей, с ОДИНАКОВЫМ методом заправки.
Используя полиморфизм, мы можем упростить ему жизнь! Опишем наши классы следующим образом:

```
public interface IRefillable
{
 void Fill();
}

abstract class Car : IRefillable
{
  string model_name;
  float f_volume;
  public void Fill()
  {
    //awesome_code
  }
}

class Car1:Car
{  }

class Car2:Car
{  }

class Car3:Car
{  }
```

Минуточку! Кода стало больше, да еще и какие то абстрактные автомобили, довольно! Нет, на самом деле теперь, у вас и у владельца станции намного больше шансов справиться с "заправкой", описываем работу станции, на основе крутых "полиморфичных" автомобилей:

```
public class Station
{
  float cost;

  public void fill_up(Car car, int liters)//Чудесно! Теперь мы можем заправить любую машину!
  {
    //awesome_code
  }

  public void fill_up(IRefillable obj, int liters) //А может быть, и не только машину!
  {
    //awesome_code
  }
}
```

И собственно, вопрос. Для чего использовать полиморфизм, кроме как для красоты и удобства кода?

Comment: Коротко говоря, для гибкости кода?

Comment: @NeulovimFox Гибкость, расширяемость, упрощение совместной работы.

Answer (score 2):

Основная цель применения *полиморфизма* — краткость программ. Короткие программы проще создавать и проще изменять.

Посмотрим на язык со строгой типизацией, но без полиморфизма, скажем, Паскаль. Если вам нужен список строк и список чисел, придётся написать две версии каждой процедуры/функции, потому что строка и число это разные типы.

C# поддерживает параметрический полиморфизм (обобщённое программирование), поэтому там есть список чего угодно — `List<T>`.

Помимо параметрического полиморфизма есть полиморфизм ad hoc, где вы всё ещё *должны* писать несколько версий функции, но пользователь вашей функции уже не должен запоминать разные названия.

В языке C# работает *перегрузка функций*:

```
int a = 1;
a += 100;

double b = 3.14;
b += 2.72;

string c = "aaa";
a += "bbb";

Action<int> d = x => Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
d += x => Console.WriteLine("{0}", 2 * x);
```

Везде мы видим оператор `+=`, который на уровне байт-кода представляет совершенно разные действия для разных типов. Удобно, что, понимая семантику оператора, вы не должны вспоминать его *имя* для конкретного типа.

Наконец, объектно-ориентированные языки предлагают концепцию *наследования* и связанный с ней полиморфизм методов. Это тоже ad hoc полиморфизм, потому что в классах-наследниках приходится писать свою версию полиморфного (виртуального) метода. Но, как мы выяснили только что, даже это упрощает если не написание, то по крайней мере использование кода.